# How to disable fingerprint from opening a locked phone, but enable for applications?

Tags: security, lock-screens

In Android 6.0.1, there is an option to 'Enable fingerprint' in **Application lock**, but it forces the phone to be unlocked via fingerprints.

Since most likely, the application lock only prevents sensitive data (messages, account information, etc.) from  being accessed/viewed easily, it makes more sense to me to selectively allow usage of fingerprint to unlock apps (and not the phone) because for the phone, a secure PIN/Password makes more sense.

Why is it so? Is there a way to achieve the desired result (using no third party tools)?

Comment: I believe you can lock applications with a password but I'm not sure about this.  Why isn't a password enough?

Comment: It's not about being enough. Since I have a fingerprint scanner on my phone, and don't want to use it to unlock my phone, why not put it to some use